# Зачем нужен sass?

Tags: sass

В шаблоне есть следующие папки:

1. css
2. fonts
3. js
4. sass

Объясните зачем папка sass? Если я захочу что-то изменить - где это нужно делать: в css, sass или может сразу в двух местах и не сломается ли проект если удалить sass?

Comment: Спросите автора проекта?..

Comment: http://sass-scss.ru

Comment: Внесу ясность: в гугле легко найти, что такое Sass, но это ничего не говорит о рабочем процессе разработчика, куда вносить изменения можно и не стоит.

Answer (score 2):

В папке SASS лежат исходники стилей в формате препроцессора SASS. Эти исходники, при сборке, компилируются в обычный CSS. Соотвественно, для того, чтобы вносить правки в проект, вам нужно править SASS файлы.

Далее, после того как вы их поправите, их нужно будет скомпилировать в CSS. В этом вопросе вам может помочь инструмент вроде Grunt или Gulp. Вот например [мануал по использованию Grunt](http://nano.sapegin.ru/all/grunt-0-4). Если же, вам кажется слишком сложным использовать командную строку, то вот еще один вариант: [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) - система сборки проекта с визуальным интерфейсом.

В самом крайнем случае, если не хочется ни с чем возиться, то создайте новый CSS файл, например patch.css. Подключите его к страницам сразу после основного CSS файла. В этом файле вы сможете просто написать что-то на обычном CSS.